using sheet/form combo for inventory --
I am using google sheets and forms combo to track inventory inputs ( # units started with) and outputs (# of units taken out per packout)
i am having an issue once new forms are submitted and new lines are formed.
for example-- one form might have 20 stickers taken out and another 10 hats.
since the formulas are not reflecting the name of the product but rather the line it is after the form is submitted-- its not working the way i was hoping.
as each form is submitted (outputs when taking out of inventory, and input when adding to inventory) I cant seem to find a way to make the master inventory sheet line up with the correct numbers for input and output since it will be on a new line each time.
any suggestions for this?
i am new to using forms rather then manually editing the sheet.
I am trying to avoid mutiple people touching the sheet and having the form data gather the numbers instead.
thank you!
i have an inventory sheet which is the master sheet.
then i created 3 forms on the sheet.
products
inputs
outputs.
my goal is to have the original master inventory sheet collect all of the inputs and outputs as products get added in when low (input), and also what the total is in stock since we take out from the inventory/stock. (output)
i really just want to be able to track inventory by using the form for input / output-- and it reflecting the sheet by using the formula SUMIF
when new forms are submitted-- this is not happening.
This is my first time doing this rather then editing a sheet manually, so i jsut need some help on figuring out how to do this.
I want to avoid multiple people editing a sheet and rely on the forms filled out to be able to see what the final inventory is after inputs and outputs are being made so we can see what is in stock instead of counting it every time.
I also want to avoid manually inputting on a sheet and use forms for this instead.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
